# Limiting input to integers in a calculator program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie of Python and I'm trying to make a program that asks the user to perform a calculation and input the result.
If the user was right the program congratulates and if the user was wrong the program simply shows the correct answer

I've done everything and (maybe not the best code) it works, my problem is: 
when the user types anything letters instead of integers it crashes

```
import random    

def app():

    numero1 = random.randint(100000, 1000000)
    numero2 = random.randint(100000, 1000000)

    if numero1 > numero2:
        print('Quanto fa ' + str(numero1) + ' - ' + str(numero2) + '?')
        answer = input()
        if int(answer) == numero1 - numero2:
            print("Esatto")
            app()
        else:
            print ("Sbagliato, fa " + str(numero1 - numero2))
            app()

    elif numero1 < numero2:
        print ('Quanto fa ' + str(numero2) + ' - ' + str(numero1) + '?')
        answer = input()
        if int(answer) == numero2 - numero1:
            print("Esatto")
            app()
        else:
            print ("Sbagliato, fa " + str(numero2 - numero1))
            app()

    elif numero1 == numero2:
        print ('Quanto fa ' + str(numero1) + ' - ' + str(numero2) + '?')
        answer = input()
        if int(answer) == numero1 - numero2:
            print("Esatto")
            app()
        else:
            print ("Sbagliato, fa " + str(numero1 - numero2))
            app()


app()
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_user_int(prompt=""):
   while True:
       try:
          return int(input(prompt))
       except ValueError:
          pass
```

then use

```
answer = get_user_int()
```

also your program could be shorter

```
if numero2 > numero1:
   numero2, numero1 = numero1, numero2
if get_user_int("{0} - {1} = ?".format(numero1,numero2)) == numero1 - numero2 :
     print ("Essato!")
else:
     print ("Answer:{0}".format(numero1-numero2)
```

alternatively instead of checking `if int(user_answer) == num1 - num2` you could safely compare strings instead `if user_anser == str(num1 - num2)`

Answer (score 0):

It is VERY likely that you **do not** want to use the `input()` function:

> *input([prompt])* Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not
>   syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions
>   may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide
>   elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> **Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.**

`input()` would allow a user to input erroneous code into your application.

consider using `raw_input()`

there are a few ways to do this (this being arguably one of the simpler ways):

```
def get_int(prompt=""):
    input = -1
    while input < 0:
        try:
            input = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))
        except ValueError as err:
            input = -1
            # Handle the error?
    return input
```

Comment: What happens if I try to enter the integer `-1` at the prompt?

Comment: it will work but it will not take it, you need a number >= 0 to break the loop.  If you wanted negative numbers you could omit while input < 0 and then while True it